# BSSID vs MAC address?

Tags: android

I don't understand the difference between MAC address and BSSID.

I understand that MAC is an identifier to local networks, but when I searched BSSID on wiki I got this:

> In an infrastructure BSS, the BSSID is the MAC address of the wireless
>   access point (WAP).

from source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29

if BSSID is the mac address of WAP, then how come MAC addresses and BSSIDs are different?

I tried this on a simple android app, when I `getConnectionInfo` I have a different BSSID from a MAC address. Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MAC address identifies a piece of hardware. The hub has a MAC address, and so does your network card which is connecting to it. The former is also the BSSID.

getConnectionInfo will be returning *your* MAC address as "MAC address", and the *hub*'s MAC address as "BSSID".

Comment: A decent answer for back in 2011, but this is only sometimes correct.  @user2456984's source notes, "the AP’s Basic Service Set Identifier (BSSID) ... is **usually** _derived from_ Access Points MAC address".  So the BSSID can be only _related to_ the MAC address(es) or even completely different.  

Not sure how SO handles the situation where an answer has been marked correct but isn't. Does voting take care of it or is there something else to do?

Comment: Found an interesting link here .. https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-space-apps/network-director2.0/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html

Answer (score 16):

The MAC address is the access point (AP) address.

Each AP can support up to 16 SSIDs (Service Set ID). Each of these SSIDs has their own MAC address derived from the AP MAC address.

For more information and to see how the BSSID derived from the MAC address please see:
https://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/Controller-Based-WLANs/How-is-the-BSSID-derived-from-the-Access-Point-ethernet-MAC/ta-p/176290

I hope this answers the question for the future viewer.

Comment: The maximum number of SSID supported by AP is vendor/product specific. There is no such limit in the standard as it's outside the scope of 802.11 specs.